# Essbase Export Dimension Hierarchy into Column Format

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, essbase

In one of my Essbase cubes, I have a Dimension with a large hierarchy. It can go down to GEN 6 or 7.

I need to have this hierarchy exported and converted into a table / column format.
It should look like this:

[image]

I have tried to export the dimension into a XML File but I don't get all the hierarchy members into a fine column format.

Does anyone have an idea or did something similar in the past?

I appreciate any hint!